# How to make a validation and show message if default value is selected in dropdown in vue

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vue-component, dropdown

I have a dropdown that I want to give a validation.

So here is my dropdown component:

```
<template>
    <div class="custom-select" :tabindex="tabindex" @blur="open = false">
        <div class="selected" :class="{ open: open }" @click="open = !open">
            {{ selected.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="items" :class="{ selectHide: !open }">
            <div v-if="defaultValue != ''">{{defaultValue}}</div>
            <div v-for="(option, i) of options" :key="i" @click=" selected = option; open = false; $emit('input', option);">
                {{ option.name }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        defaultValue: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "Choose an option",
        },
        tabindex: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            open: false,
            selected: this.setDefaultValue(),
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$emit("input", this.selected);
    },
    methods: {
        setDefaultValue () {
            if (this.defaultValue == '' && this.options.length > 0) {
                return this.options[0];
            }
            return { name: this.defaultValue};
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

and in my parent component, I am using this dropdown, the fetched value from API call and filled with variations. So what I am trying to do is if the value is not selected (default: "Choose an option"), I want to give an error message which is saying, the dropdown is mandatory.

```
<Dropdown
                            :options="getVariations"
                            class="select"
                            @input="getSelected"
                        />

<script>

import Dropdown from "../components/Dropdown";
import apiHelper from "../helpers/apiHelper";

export default {
    components: {Dropdown},
    data() {
        return {
            selected: "",
            variationId: "",
            selectedObject: null
        };
    },
    computed: {
        getVariations() {
            return this.product.attributes.variations
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSelected(opt) {
            this.selectedObject = opt;
            this.selected = opt.description;
            this.variationId = opt.id;
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of what you are asking for:

```
// v-model property
selectedVModel: null

// html 
<select id="testselect" v-model="selectedVModel" required>
   <option :value="null">Default</option>
   <option value="bar">Option 1</option>
   <option value="foo">Option 2</option>
   <option value="baz">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div v-if="!selectedVModel">Error! Choose something!</div>
```

You can handle the error inside of your child component. In this example, if the `v-model` as `selectedVModel` is empty, the `<div>` with `v-if="!selectedVModel"` will be shown. As `selectedVModel` is `null` it will automatically select `<option :value="null">Default</option>`. If you chosse one of the options `selectedVModel` get´s a value so `v-if="!selectedVModel"` results into `false`, no error then. If you select `Default` again, the value turns to `null` again which results into `true` at `v-if="!selectedVModel"`, so the error will be visible again.

Combine this simple example with your code and let me know if it helped you.